# Onclick class function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

[image]

```
<form id="overideCommentForm" >
    <td><span id="1" class="btn btn-danger  reject-student  view-button">Not Selected</span></td><td><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="comment"></td>
    <td><span id="2" class="btn btn-danger  reject-student  view-button">Not Selected</span></td><td><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="comment"></td>
    <td><span id="3" class="btn btn-danger  reject-student  view-button">Not Selected</span></td><td><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="comment"></td>
    <td><span id="4" class="btn btn-danger  reject-student  view-button">Not Selected</span></td><td><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="comment"></td>
</form>
```

```js
$("#overideCommentForm").on('click', ".view-button", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('reject-student').addClass('select-student').text('Selected');
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".overrideStudent").show();
});
$("#overideCommentForm").on( "click", ".reject-student", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('select-student').addClass('reject-student').text('Not Selected Details');
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".overrideStudent").hide();
});
```

From the above image i am trying to change the Selected button to Not selected when i select the student the comment box has to appear if Not selected the comment text has to disapper.

I have tried the above code but the

```
$("#overideCommentForm").on('click', ".view-button", function() {
```

is not working if replace the line with  `$(document)` it is not working as well what is the problem..?

the button are coming dynamically with while-loop

Comment: There will be a `SyntaxError` in the console

Comment: `$('#overideCommentForm')`. Always watch out for errors on console

Comment: You have one typo on your code: `$(#overideCommentForm)`should be `$("#overideCommentForm")`

Comment: Besides the typo in your JS code you also have used `</from>` instead of `</form>`. I'd strongly suggest you use an editor with syntax highlighting. It makes it practically impossible to miss basic errors like this

Comment: Your closing tag of the form element has a typo: `</from>` should be `</form>`

Comment: Take a note that is called ***Invalid Markup***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have missed double quotes

```
$("#overideCommentForm").on("click", ".view-button", function() {
```

Comment: i have tried with double quotations still not working.

Comment: resolved that typo as well.. actually this form is in `tbody`  is that fine..?

Comment: form tag cannot be nested inside tbody